# jq substr() equivalent to format a value

Tags: json, string, slice, jq, substr

Hope you are fine in these times.

I am floored with a problem and I hope you have more knowledge.

Using 'jq' I want to change all the dates from eg. 19731013 (string) to a 1973-10-13

```
[
    {
        "Mail": "john@example.com",
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Employee_Number": "000555",
        "First_Name": "John",
        "Company": "ACME",
        "Department": null,
        "Employment_Status": "Retiree",
        "Start_Date": "19770516",
        "Function_Start_Date": "19770516",
        "Group_Phone": "",
        "Job_Title": "Operations Manager Warehousing",
        "Sub_Group": "Exempts",
        "Location": "Tibuktu",
        "Organizational_Unit": null,
        "Date_of_Birth": "19560719",
        "Gender": "1"
    },
    {
        "Mail": "mary@example.com",
        "Name": "Smith",
        "Employee_Number": "000777",
        "First_Name": "Mary",
        "Company": "ACME",
        "Department": null,
        "Employment_Status": "Retiree",
        "Start_Date": "19770516",
        "Function_Start_Date": "19770516",
        "Group_Phone": "",
        "Job_Title": "Manager",
        "Sub_Group": "Exempts",
        "Location": "Tibuktu",
        "Organizational_Unit": null,
        "Date_of_Birth": "19560719",
        "Gender": "2"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to use `substr(.Start_Date,1,5)"-"substr(.Start_Date,6,2)"-"substr(.Start_Date,8,3)` like with awk in a CSV?

Maybe I am staring at a wall while missing the door on the right?

UPDATE: Thanks a lot guys this worked like a charm!

```
jq -r '.[].Start_Date |= "\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8])" | .[].Function_Start_Date |= "\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8])" | .[].Date_of_Birth|="\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8])"' employees.json > test.json
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JQ we have [string slice](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Array/StringSlice:.[10:15]) and [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) syntaxes for that.

```
$ jq '.[].Start_Date | "\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8])"' file
"1977-05-16"
"1977-05-16"
```

Comment: Thank you! I am liking jq more and more. Its very powerful once you get to know what it can do and the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

There is also regex match function in `jq` using `capture` that emits named captured groups, which can be later joined by `-` to form the date strings like you wanted.

```
jq '.[].Start_Date | capture("(?<x>[0-9]{4})(?<y>[0-9]{2})(?<z>[0-9]{2})") | join("-")'
```

This is assuming, your `Start_Date` field is atleast 8 chars long and does *not* validate for lengths lesser than that.

Comment: Thanks Inian. Thanks to you I learned two things today.  capture()